# EXTJS bar chart vertical bar is not coming at correct(center) position. How to make it?

Tags: extjs, bar-chart, extjs5, sencha-cmd

[image]I am trying to change the width of the bar in extjs bar chart. While changing bar width, it is moving to left side. It is not coming in correct(center) position

fiddle link : https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2sfi

I tried to set align center. but it is not working

```
Ext.application({
name : 'Fiddle',

    launch : function() {
        var chart = Ext.create('Ext.chart.CartesianChart', {
            legend       : {
                docked : 'right'
            },
            insetPadding : 40,
            flipXY       : false,
            store        : {
                fields : ['month', 'data1', 'data2', 'data3', 'data4' ],
                data   : [
                    { month : 1, data1 : 20, data2 : 37, data3 : 35, data4 : 4 },
                    { month : 2, data1 : 20, data2 : 37, data3 : 36, data4 : 5 },
                    { month : 3, data1 : 19, data2 : 36, data3 : 37, data4 : 4 },
                    { month : 4, data1 : 18, data2 : 36, data3 : 38, data4 : 5 },
                    { month : 5, data1 : 18, data2 : 35, data3 : 39, data4 : 4 },
                    { month : 6, data1 : 17, data2 : 34, data3 : 42, data4 : 4 },
                    { month : 7, data1 : 16, data2 : 34, data3 : 43, data4 : 4 },
                    { month : 8, data1 : 16, data2 : 33, data3 : 44, data4 : 4 },
                    { month : 9, data1 : 16, data2 : 32, data3 : 44, data4 : 4 },
                    { month : 10, data1 : 16, data2 : 32, data3 : 45, data4 : 4 },
                    { month : 11, data1 : 15, data2 : 31, data3 : 46, data4 : 4 },
                    { month : 12, data1 : 15, data2 : 31, data3 : 47, data4 : 4 }
                ]
            },
            axes         : [
                {
                    type              : 'numeric',
                    position          : 'left',
                    adjustByMajorUnit : true,
                    fields            : 'data1',
                    grid              : true,

                    minimum           : 0
                },
                {
                    type     : 'category',
                    position : 'bottom',
                    fields   : 'month',
                    grid     : true
                }
            ],
            series       : [
                {
                    type    : 'bar',
                    title   : [ 'IE'],
                    xField  : 'month',
                    yField  : [ 'data1'],
                    renderer: function(sprite, record, attr, index, store) {
                    return Ext.apply(attr, {
                        width: 1,
                    });
                    },
                    stacked : false
                }
            ]
        });


        Ext.create('Ext.Window', {
            width       : 500,
            height      : 400,
            title       : 'Grouped Bar Chart',
            autoShow    : true,
            layout      : 'fit',
            items       : chart
        });[![enter image description here][1]][1]
    }
});
```

the bar need to be come in the position of 1(horizontal) not before one
if i removed belllow code from renderer, bar width is getting increase and it is aligning correctly.

return Ext.apply(attr, {
                            width: 1,
                        });

Comment: Have you tried using `maxBarWidth: 1` instead?

Comment: I tried. it is not working as expected. The bar width in not reducing to expected width

Comment: after adding maxBarWidth inside style it is working fine. thanks incutonez

Answer (score 1):

After setting maxBarWidth bars are aligning at correct position.

style: {
                opacity: 1,
                stroke: 10,
                maxBarWidth: 1
            }